# Prevent default attribute routing behaviour when no route attribute is specified on a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When using only attribute routing in an ASP.NET Core 5.0 app, for example, with the following in `Startup`:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

A controller class with a single public method that has no route attribute will still be matched to a `GET` request that otherwise matches that controller.

For example `GET api/test` will match the `Index` method below (it doesn't matter what the method is called) even though the method doesn't have a route attribute:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If, however, another public method is added to that controller class, also without an attribute, an `AmbiguousMatchException` is thrown for `GET api/test` because routing can't otherwise figure out which method to use.

If a `[HttpGet]` attribute is added to one of those methods, the issue is resolved.

I understand that one solution is to just ensure that all methods have appropriate route attributes, or that only one method on the controller is public.

Is there a way to prevent this default/fallback behaviour where methods that don't have explicit attributes are still matched?

Can attribute routing be configured to only match methods that have explicit routing attributes on them?

Comment: I can't check it right now, but I guess you can add some custom midleware right after your `app.UseRouting();` call in a `Startup.Configure` method. Something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#aspnet-core-endpoint-definition)

Comment: Perhaps you could do something with an [IActionDescriptorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.abstractions.iactiondescriptorprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the route to:

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}")]
```

Will indicate that action has to be specified, it will not default to anything unless you specify default action like this:

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{action=Index}")]
```

Edit:

If you want to be forced to be explicit about the routes, then you can remove the [Route()] attribute from controller level and add it above every action like this

```
[ApiController]
public class TestController
{
    [Route("api")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]/asdf")]
    [Route("api/[controller]/asdf/{id?}")]
    public IActionResult Index2(int? id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The code will then not compile unless every action has a Route() attribute or other similar attributes like HttpGet(), HTTpPost() etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt. This does indeed work and is a more elegant way of resolving the symptom, however, I was kind of hoping to find a solution that disabled the matching of undecorated methods; this solution really just ensures that the correct undecorated method is picked by the router. This may be the only way as intended by the ASP.NET Core developers, so unless another more specific answer comes along shortly, I'll accept this one.

Comment: I don't understand what is your end goal, what you are describing is basically not having a controller mapped to a route. Why would you need controller actions if they are not mapped to a route and cannot be reached? Have you considered endpoints.Map() function?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to turn off (not workaround) this seemingly fallback behaviour. Workarounds have unintended consequences, e.g. your solution breaks other routes like `[HttpGet("{id}")]` on a method. As I (sort of) said in my question, one solution is to just not have public methods on a controller. However, for example (as how I came across this), if someone adds a public method to a base class that is inherited by the controller, then it suddenly breaks all controllers. It just feels like that shouldn't happen unless I ask it to. I'd rather it *require* a `[HttpGet]` or give a 404.

Comment: An action annotated with `[HttpGet("{id}")]` is going to execute at `/api/test/<actionname>/3` . If you really like to be explicit about every route then you can remove the statement from a controller and annotate above every action, in that case the code simply won't compile if you add another action and won't annotate it.

Comment: Your comment regarding removing the controller level annotation is the best fit. This ensures all routes are explicitly defined and prevents the inadvertent introduction of unexpected behaviour. Would you like to update your answer to include this?